# Find nearest by index numbers in array less than number at given index

Tags: algorithm, optimization, complexity-theory

This is an algorithm optimization problem.

I have an integer array `A` and want to build array `B` such that `B[i]` contains index `j` of the element in `A[j]` such that (`B[i] = j`)

```
1. j > i
2. A[j] < A[i]
3. j is minimum of all possible j's.
```

For example if `A` is:

```
   A = [1,5,6,4,3,1,2]
```

Then `B` will be (indexing from 0)

```
   B = [-1,3,3,4,5,-1,-1]
```

`B[0] = -1` because there is no numbers less than `1` with indices more than `0`. 
`B[1] = 3` because `A[3]` is the right-closest element to index `1` in `A` that contains number less than `A[1]=5`. And so forth.

I know the solution with `O(n*log(n))` complexity using binary search tree. How can I enhance the complexity to `O(n)` or prove that it is impossible?

Comment: checked again, b[1] is not equal to 2 because a[2] = 6 > 5 = a[1]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless I misunderstand the problem, you can solve it in a simple left-to-right scan, keeping a stack of indices for which you have not yet encountered a smaller element. (The values corresponding to the indices on the stack must be monotonically non-decreasing, for obvious reasons.)

For each value in the input list, while that value is less than the value corresponding to the top index (if any) of the stack, set the corresponding element of the output list to the index of the current input value and pop the stack.

The following little Python program illustrates:

```
def ind(a):
  b = [-1] * len(a)
  stack = []
  for i in range(len(a)):
    v = a[i]
    while stack and a[stack[-1]] > v:
      j = stack.pop()
      b[j] = i
    stack.append(i)
  return b
```

Proof that it is `O(n)`: The for loop is clearly executed `n` times. The body of the while loop executes (in total) at most `n` times, since it can only happen once for each element. Or, to put it another way, every element is pushed and popped at most once.

Comment: You did not misunderstood, everything is right, thank you! I totally forgot that I can use stack